# Creating a clean hover effect with text over an image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, hover, bootstrap-4

I'm building a website with Bootstrap 4. I've created a set of thumbnail images with text overlays, and I created a hover effect that changes the color of the image when moused over. However, the effect goes away when hovering over the text overlay. Any ideas for how to maintain the effect when hovering over the text?

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="row learn_more">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-6 learn_more-item">
        <a href="/work/index.html" class="learn_more-link">
            <div class="learn_more-hover">
            </div>
            <img src="img/work.png" class="img-fluid" alt="work">
            <div class="learn_more-text">
                <p>Work</p>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-6 learn_more-item">
        <a href="/about/index.html" class="learn_more-link">
            <div class="learn_more-hover">
            </div>
            <img src="img/about.png" class="img-fluid" alt="about">
            <div class="learn_more-text">
                <p>About</p>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is my CSS:

```
.learn_more-link {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}

.learn_more-hover {
    background: rgba(221, 33, 99, 0.75);
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
}

.learn_more-hover:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}

.learn_more * {
    z-index: 2;
}

.learn_more img {
    opacity: 0.25;
}

.learn_more-text {
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    font-size: 2rem;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

**EDIT:**

Thanks to your suggestions, I cleaned up the code as follows.

HTML:

```
<div class="row learn_more">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-6 learn_more-item">
        <a href="/work/index.html" class="learn_more-link">
            <img src="img/work.png" class="img-fluid" alt="work"><span class="learn_more-text">Work</span>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-6 learn_more-item">
        <a href="/about/index.html" class="learn_more-link">
            <img src="img/about.png" class="img-fluid" alt="about"><span class="learn_more-text">About</span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.learn_more-link {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}

.learn_more-link:hover {
    background: rgba(221, 33, 99, 0.75);
}

.learn_more img {
    opacity: 0.25;
}

.learn_more-text {
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    font-size: 2rem;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Removed Some HTML

HTML

```
<div class="row learn_more">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-6 learn_more-item">
        <a href="/work/index.html" class="learn_more-link">
            <img src="https://storage.googleapis.com/gweb-uniblog-publish-prod/static/blog/images/google-200x200.7714256da16f.png" class="img-fluid" alt="work">
            <div class="learn_more-text">
                <p>Work</p>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.learn_more-link {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}

.learn_more-item:hover{
  background-color: rgba(221, 33, 99, 0.75);;
}

.learn_more img {
    opacity: 0.25;
}

.learn_more-text {
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    font-size: 2rem;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Try this .. and style accordingly

hope this helps..

Answer (score 1):

Removed some html codes and rearranged div blocks..

```
<div class="row learn_more">

<div class="col-md-3 col-6 learn_more-item">

    <a href="/work/index.html" class="learn_more-link">
        <img src="img/work.png" class="img-fluid" alt="work"><span>Work</span>

    </a>

</div>

<div class="col-md-3 col-6 learn_more-item">

    <a href="/about/index.html" class="learn_more-link">

        <img src="img/about.png" class="img-fluid" alt="about"><span>About</span>

    </a>

</div>
```

```
.learn_more-link 
{
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}

.learn_more-link:hover 
{
    background: rgba(221, 33, 99, 0.75);
}


.learn_more img 
{
    opacity: 0.25;
}

span
{
    font-size:20px;
    margin-left:30px;
}
```

Hope this helps..

Comment: This answer got me very close. I just needed to style the text to center within the image. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to give hover effect to

`.learn_more-item{/*your code here*/}`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```css
.hovereffect {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: default;
}

.hovereffect .overlay {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgba(75,75,75,0.7);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.hovereffect:hover .overlay {
  background-color: rgba(186, 0, 34, 0.52);
}

.hovereffect img {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

.hovereffect h2 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 17px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(45px);
  -ms-transform: translateY(45px);
  transform: translateY(45px);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.hovereffect:hover h2 {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(5px);
  -ms-transform: translateY(5px);
  transform: translateY(5px);
  margin:0px;
}

.hovereffect p.text {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 7px 14px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  background-color: transparent;
  opacity: 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  -webkit-transform: scale(0);
  -ms-transform: scale(0);
  transform: scale(0);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin: 7px;
}

.hovereffect:hover p.text {
  opacity: 1;
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
}

.hovereffect p.text:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <h1>Hover Effect</h1>
 <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="hovereffect">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://cableandmedia.com/abranew/img/banner/3.jpg" alt="">
            <div class="overlay">
               <h2>Your Title</h2>
               <p class="text">Your dummy text
               <a href="#">read more</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not bad, but not 100% what I was looking for. Thanks.